# Why this program gives segmention fault in this queue program

Tags: c, pointers, scope, initialization, function-call

This is the C program for queue. I have just written it for insert values. The problem I am getting is I get segmentation fault whenever I insert the first element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
struct node{
        int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct queue {
    struct node *front;
    struct node *rear;
};

struct queue *q;

void create_queue(struct queue *);
struct queue *insert(struct queue *,int);

int main()
{

int val, option;
create_queue(q);

do
{

printf("\n *****MAIN MENU*****");       
printf("\n 1. INSERT");     
printf("\n Enter your option : ");
scanf("%d", &option);

switch(option)
        {
            case 1:             
                                printf("\n Enter the number to insert in the queue:");
                scanf("%d", &val);
                q = insert(q,val);
                break;

        }

}while(option != 5);

return 0;
}

void create_queue(struct queue *q)
{
    q = (struct queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->rear = NULL;//how this happened without any error??
    q->front = NULL;
}

struct queue *insert(struct queue *q,int val)
{

struct node *ptr;

ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("error in allocating\n");
    return -1;
}
    ptr->data = val;
    if(q->front == NULL)
    {
        q->front = ptr;//here I get segmentation fault
        q->rear = ptr;
        q->front->next = q->rear->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        q->rear->next = ptr;
        q->rear = ptr;
        q->rear->next = NULL;
    }

return q;
}
```

what is wrong with my program?
Why the assignment of a new node does not work, what is the current syntax?

Comment: `create_queue()` makes all local changes.....

Comment: q is a pointer here. so any changes to its elements will be saved. Isn't it?

Comment: The memory that is allocated in `create_queue` is not returned anywhere so you are causing undefined behaviour by using q when it hasn't been assigned. Going line by line with a debugger would show this easily. Either return the pointer or use `**`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen In case of globals, we have a shortcut, at least theoretically. I'm not preaching the practice, though. :)

Comment: This is an example given in a book data structures through C-Reema Thareja page no : 258. The example didn't even did local malloc as I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, while you call functions with the global variable and accept that in a function parameter, the function parameter becomes local to the called function.

This way, the local variable shadows the global variable and since C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing, any changes made to the local copy is not reflected to the caller, anyway.

Finally, the global pointer `p` remains uninitialized. Attempt to dereference that causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You either

- don't need to pass the global(s) as parameter
- pass the address of the pointer and operate on the same inside the function.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: yes the program works if I do malloc before calling create_queue(q)

Comment: @acidlategamer that way you _avoid_ the problem with shadowing. :)